# Bitwise OR function in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, aggregate-functions, sqlclr, bitwise-or

I want to create a custom bitwise OR aggregate function.
I want to use it like the built in aggregate functions (MIN, MAX etc.)

```
SELECT dbo.bitwise_or(bit_string) FROM table
```

where bit_string is a nvarchar(3)

so for example if the table contains two rows ('100', '001') the above query should return '101'

I would like to implement this as a CLR function/assembly with the aggregate below:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE dbo.bitwise_or (bit_string nvarchar(3))
RETURNS [nvarchar(3)]
EXTERNAL NAME [Aggregate].[bitwise_or]
```

Can someone give me a jump start with the c# code?

I have followed this post to implement amedian aggregate function: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+CLR/3208/
but there is a lot of code (not sure what is really needed in my case)

Answer (score 0):

This link pretty much explains it all: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91e6taax(v=vs.90).aspx

1. Create a SQL Server project in VS
2. Add Item
3. Select Aggregate
4. Type name for it
5. Write code:

using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

```
[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.Native)]
public struct Bitwise_or
{
  //Implement the function below

  // Initialize any reource here, called once
  public void Init()
  {
  }

  // Decides what action to take for each row value
  public void Accumulate()
  {
  }    

  // Used by SQL Server when large amount of data is processed
  public void Merge()
  {
  }    

  // Free up resources
  public void Terminate()
  {
  }    
}
```

1. Build
2. deploy your project and it will be available in SQL Server.